# Match template histogram with testing histogram

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram, histogram-equalization

How can we calculate the percentage of similarities between two pattern of Histogram?

For example, I have a histogram of template which I called `HistA`, and I have another histogram which is `HistB` where I want to check the similarities percentage of `HistB` with `HistA`.

I tried check out some of method such as histogram equalization, histogram matching but none of them works with my problem.

[image]

As image below, I create a multiple histogram between `HistA` and `HistB`. The value of the frequencies were actually value from a 1D data.

I saw the pattern of `HistA` and `HistB` almost the same, so I want to know how to calculate the percentage of the similarities of this two histogram.

Comment: So this it not an attempt to answer your question, but more of a methodological comment... Since the counts in your plot are less than 1, I suppose the histograms actually represent some empirical probability density function estimates, correct? Is percentage similarity a suitable metric for comparing PDFs? Other options such as the [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) come to mind.

Comment: Perhaps, `corr` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Measure **Bhattacharya co-efficient** between the two **normalized** histograms [image] and [image] as

[image]

where N is the number of bins in the histograms.

---

Note the **normalization**.

For more information, see [Bhattacharya distance|Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance) or [On a measure of divergence between two statistical populations defined by their probability distributions](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0010358).